# Allow Elasticbeanstalk application to access EC-2 instance without using a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently I have an application which is running on a normal Ubuntu EC-2 instance as well as an elasticbeanstalk environment running a Tomcat Web Application. There is a server on the EC-2 instance which must be accessible from the elasticbeanstalk application at all times.

The issue here is that I cannot associate the elasticbeanstalk application with a Security Group, I have tried adding an options.config file to the .ebextensions folder in the root web project containing the following:

```
  option_settings:
   - namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
   - option_name: SecurityGroups
   - value: 'sg-XXXXXX'
```

But this doesn't work. The EC-2 instance always has a static IP-address, however, the instances accessing the EC-2 server is changing inside of AWS. I read that if two services are assigned to the same security group they will be able to communicate with eachother. The issue with that approach is that I cannot even change the security group of the elasticbeanstalk application whatsoever.

I cannot allow global access to the server either, it must be specific to the elasticbeanstalk environment only.

Due to circumstances I cannot dig into right now, we won't be able to launch the instances in a VPC for the moment, but we need the services running regardless.

I cannot find any decent documentation on how to achieve any of this, if any of you have a hunch I'd be more than happy to receive any suggestions or directions as to how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All instances will be in a security group. It sounds like your beanstalk instances are probably in some default security group. You can view each instance in the EC2 console and see what security group they are in. Also, just having instances in the same security group does not guarantee that they can communicate with each other. Whoever told you that is wrong.

You just need to figure out what security groups your instances are in, and then modify the rules in the security group(s) to allow the appropriate access.

Also, note that you can't change an instance's security group after it has been created. You would have to terminate the instance and create a new one in the group you want. However, like I said, you shouldn't need to change the security groups at all in order to fix this issue.

Comment: I had to create a new security group and add it to the EC-2 instances Security group in the inbound tab. On top of that I had to use the **internal** (or private) hostname for the instance for it to work properly.